# Percents in PowerBI multiselect?

Tags: powerbi

I have a chart that displays the percent of users who use a certain feature on an app.  I filter by which version of the app they are using, and am trying to implement multiselect.  However, PowerBI adds the percents together which messes up the proportions (and results in percents above 100).  Is there any workaround for this?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to provide more detail about how your data is structured and any Measure formulae involved.

Comment: @MikeHoney I calculate the percentages by dividing the number of users who use a feature for a specific version by the total number of users for that version. When I select more than one version, Power BI simply adds the percentages together rather than adding the user counts and recalculating. 

If version 1 has 10 users of the feature and 100 total users, its percent should show as 10%

If version 2 has 40 users of the feature and 200 total users, its percent should show as 20%

If version 1 and 2 are both selected, the percent should show as 50/300 = 17% rather than 30%.

Answer (score 1):

Your question hasnt been specific enough to be sure, but it sounds like you have implemented your percentage calculation either in the Edit Queries window or as a Calculated Column ("New Column").  I would normally create that type of calculation as a New Measure, so it occurs after the data is summarised.  For example"

`Percent of Users = COUNTDISTINCT ( 'Feature Uses'[User Id] ) / COUNTDISTINCT ( 'Version Uses'[User Id] )`